# C++ - Need a stack of array of a type that can outlive a stack frame

Tags: c++

I have a need for an array of my types, that need to be put on a std::stack, and I need that this be available to me throughout the program and where I pass it, without being tied to the current stack frame.

I'm confused on which is the right/appropriate/better declaration:

```
 std::stack<MyClass*> *myvariable = new ...
```

OR

```
 std::stack<MyClass[]> *myvariable = new ...
```

OR

any other suggestion that meets my needs.

Comment: `std::stack<MyClass> myvariable` unless you have really good reasons to do otherwise.

Comment: I want it to outlive my stack frame. I'll be passing it around.

Comment: Also, I need an array ...

Comment: Maybe you should put that information in the question.

Comment: You're more likely to get useful answers if you explain what actual problem you are trying to solve.  What is the most appropriate data type very much depends on that.

Comment: If you need an array inside a stack, you could try std::stack<std::array<MyClass,sizeOfArray>>

Comment: Sounds like you want `std::stack<std::vector<MyClass>>`.

Comment: @Galik -- yes that's what I want! Thank you!

Comment: And if I want to not copy it .. or pass it -- std::stack<std::vector<MyClass>> mystack, .. or a *mystack?

How can I be sure I'm not copying things when I don't intend to? (Without having to goto SO every time)

Comment: You need to put in some actual code... we can't just guess what it is that you want.